# Create a Postgres boolean function that handles nulls

Tags: postgresql-11

I'm trying to create a function that will cast boolean values to `'t'` or `'f'`, or `''` if NULL.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION bool(b BOOLEAN) RETURNS VARCHAR
AS $$
BEGIN
IF b IS NULL THEN 
    RETURN ''; 
END IF;
IF b THEN 
    RETURN 't'; 
ELSE
    RETURN 'f';
END IF;
END; 
$$ LANGUAGE PLPGSQL CALLED ON NULL INPUT;
```

However, the following always returns NULL. What gives?

```
SELECT bool(NULL)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`bool` is also a built-in function and type cast (because there is a data  type with that name).

You need to either explicitly reference your function by prefixing it with the schema:

```
select public.bool(null);
```

or give your function a different name.

---

Unrelated, but: your function can be simplified to:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION bool(b BOOLEAN) 
  RETURNS VARCHAR
AS $$  
  select coalesce(case when b then 't' else 'f' end, '');
$$
language sql
called on null input;
```

Comment: `b::text` yields 'true' which is why I have the function in the first place, but this was definitely it. Thanks!

Comment: @GustavBertram: ah, right. See my edit. In general you should prefer `language sql` over `language plpgsql` for simply things like that.